# Modified entity is not applied into the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I am trying to update loan balance based on the payment made by a member.
Payment goes well and it is inserted as expected but during the update of the table LOANBAl, nothing is modified, bellow is my code:

```
public void UpdateLoanBal(MPAreceipting mpa, string id)
    {
        using (BOSAEntities db = new BOSAEntities())
        {
            General gn = new General();
            gn.GetUser();
            gn.GetServerDate();

            LoanRepayment lr = new LoanRepayment();
            lr.GetMemberDeduction(loanno);
            var lOANBAL = db.LOANBALs.Find(id);
            var lb = new LOANBAL();

            lb.AuditID = gn.sysUser;
            lb.AuditTime = gn.serverDate;
            lb.Balance = Convert.ToDecimal(lr.loanBalance);
            lb.IntrOwed = Convert.ToDecimal(lr.intOwed);
            lb.LastDate = mpa.dateDeposited;


            db.Entry(lOANBAL).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you never modify the `lOANBAL` object in your code. You create a new object called `lb` and modify that, but you never add it to the database. So you have one object from the database which is unchanged, and one new object which is changed but never associated with the database. I think you probably want to be updating the `lOANBAL` object instead of making a whole new one.

Comment: you meant this:     db.Entry(lb).State = EntityState.Modified;  ?

Comment: no because `lb` is not taken from your database, instead you made it with a `new` variable. It's not clear - do you want to insert a new record into the LOANBALs table, or update an existing one?

Comment: update the existing one lb was used since im assigning some changed variable which needs to be updated i.e  lb.Balance = Convert.ToDecimal(lr.loanBalance);
            lb.IntrOwed = Convert.ToDecimal(lr.intOwed);
            lb.LastDate = mpa.dateDeposited;   ....

Comment: Like I said, you can just change the properties of the `lOANBAL` object and then save it back to the database again - it represents the record you want to update, so that's what you need to change. That's whole point of using Entity Framework like this. You would only create a brand new object (like your `lb`) if you want to insert a totally new record into the database. I'm not sure how you thought changing `lb` was going to cause `lOANBAL` to be updated - they are completely unrelated objects. How did you think they were linked, exactly? I'm not following your logic on that one...

Comment: Okay let me rephrase it, I have two tables i.e Repay and Loanbal...When I insert data to repay, I should update Loanbal too based on the values inserted to repay. I am new to EF.

Comment: @CheruiyotAKirui is my comment not clear in some way? Please let know which things you don't understand. If you want to update your existing record, then update the properties of `lOANBAL` and get rid of `lb`. Do you understand? Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @ADyson perfect! did this  var lOANBAL = db.LOANBALs.Find(loanno);
                    General gn = new General();
                    gn.GetUser();
                    gn.GetServerDate();
                    LoanRepayment lr = new LoanRepayment();
                    lr.GetMemberDeduction(loanno);
                    lOANBAL.LoanNo = loanno;
                    lOANBAL.AuditID = gn.sysUser;
                    lOANBAL.AuditTime = gn.serverDate;
                    lOANBAL.Balance = Convert.ToDecimal(lr.loanBalance);

Comment: I suggest you write this as an answer - you can answer your own question, and accept your own answer. Then future readers can understand the solution easily.

Answer (score 1):

I used the lOANBAL which is an entity and update its properties.

```
 public void UpdateLoanBal(MPAreceipting mpa, string id)
    {
        var db = new BOSAEntities();
        using (var dbContextTransaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                var lOANBAL = db.LOANBALs.Find(loanno);
                General gn = new General();
                gn.GetUser();
                gn.GetServerDate();
                LoanRepayment lr = new LoanRepayment();
                lr.GetMemberDeduction(loanno);
                lOANBAL.LoanNo = loanno;
                lOANBAL.AuditID = gn.sysUser;
                lOANBAL.AuditTime = gn.serverDate;
                lOANBAL.Balance = Convert.ToDecimal(lr.loanBalance);
                lOANBAL.IntrOwed = Convert.ToDecimal(lr.intOwed);
                lOANBAL.LastDate = mpa.dateDeposited;
                lOANBAL.TransactionNo=lr.

                db.Entry(lOANBAL).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException Exc)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
                string errormessage = string.Join(";",
                    Exc.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
                throw new DbEntityValidationException(errormessage);
            }
        }
    }
```